# The awards testify to the quality / The awards are testimony to the quality -- is there any difference?

Tags: meaning-in-context, style

Is there a difference between **give testimony** (or just "are testimony) and **testify** in the marketing promotional text context?

> The awards that the company won at the 100 Best Goods of Russia competition are **testimony** to the quality of our products.

> The awards that the company won at the 100 Best Goods of Russia competition **testify** to the high quality of our products.

Are they interchangeable, or is one more preferred than the other stylistically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall *meaning* is the same, but the words are not interchangeable because one is a noun and one is a verb.

Something that *testifies* (verb, the act of testifying) gives a *testimony* (noun). It is like the difference between speaking, and a speech.

The difference is really down to a style choice - do you want to focus on the testimony, or the one giving it? For example, in the sentence "I heard a speech by the president", the speech is the object; whereas in "I heard the president speaking", the president is the object. The meaning may be the same, but arguably the second example places greater emphasis on the one speaking.